# How I can handling success logon with C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have C# application and can monitoring Logoff and SystemShutdown events

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SystemEvents_SessionEnding;
        Console.ReadLine();  //This is needed to keep the application running.
    }

    static void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionEndReasons.Logoff:
                MessageBox.Show("User logging off");
                break;

            case SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown:
                MessageBox.Show("System is shutting down");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

please help me , how I can monitor (get event) user Logon event?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running as windows service you should use SessionSwitch handler for logon session.

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
        private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Reason==SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you should use SessionSwitch event:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SystemEvents_SessionEnding;
            SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
            Console.ReadLine();  //This is needed to keep the application running.
        }

        static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Reason)
            {
                case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon:
                    //do something
                    break;
            }
        }
```